# Apply Progress Bar style globally android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-styles

I have created custom ProgressBar style as below

```
  <style name="ProgressBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:maxHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progressbar</item>
  </style>
```

And I am using as

```
<ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/gpuProgress"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:progress="50"
          style="@style/ProgressBarStyle"
          />
```

But my problem is I **dont want to apply this style to every progressbar**, that's why I **want to use as globally** but It doesn't work.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- I tried as below but its not working. -->
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

`<item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBarStyle</item>`.